# Alert not displaying properly in JavaME

Tags: java-me, alert, midp, lcdui

any ideas why the Alert dialog in Java ME application is not displaying properly (white stripe on a top of it) on a real phone (N82), it works well on an emulator. So it is not a matter of coding I suppose. See screenshots:

[image: N82 screen capture] -> N82

[image: Emulator screen capture] -> Emulator

any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Alerts and other Gui components are device's impementation depended. That means these GUI objects are "native" GUI.
You can solve this issue by creating your own GUI over Canvas, like J4ME, J2MEPolish and LWUIT.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is most likely a bug in N82.

Think of it - [lcdui Alert API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Alert.html) does not allow developer anything that would anyhow be related to "pixel rendering" artifacts like [shown at your screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no9gZ.jpg). Only things application developer can impact in Alert are like text of the title and alert, timeout value, stuff like that - and judging by your [emulator screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwHli.jpg), it looks like your code does its part right (although one can't be 100% sure about that since you didn't show the snippet of the code you use).

The whole point of high level API provided in [Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Screen.html) objects like Alert is that rendering is expected to be done by implementation. Because of that, whenever you notice rendering artifacts at high level screens you use, the most reasonable explanation would be the bug in the way how MIDP is implemented at particular device.

Comment: @Lucifer I expanded the answer (as opposed to previous one, this answer turned out salvageable:)

Comment: Yes, Now It looks perfact one. +1 for it